# Add all the photos inside the phone's gallery to scroll view?

Tags: android

I am trying to add  all the photos inside to scrollview, but i don't now where to start, any tupe of idea? Thanks.

Comment: please read these: [page1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [page2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [page3](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Listview of all pictures.  [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.html) added in api level 1.  You probably need all the thumbnails.  You'll have to also know what a URI is.  [URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) its just a string to me but they system can read it and knows what the string is like a picture or video.

Good Luck.